# Why does reputation change for a day show up as 0 if it is +10?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I noticed something strange when looking at reputation changes for [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky?tab=reputation): the reputation change for September 17th shows up as zero. If you expand it however you see one upvote:

[image]

Now I suspected that he might have downvoted ten answers on this day (reputation change from these downvotes doesn't appear in the list for other people's accounts). Problem is, he only downvoted two posts in total so far.

Things get even weirder if you use a different link to have [September 17th rating immediately expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky?tab=reputation&StartDate=2011-09-17) - all the sudden the reputation change for that day is 10:

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Showing unaccepts actually required quite a large refactor in the existing implementation, and a few bugs such as this popped up in the process.