# Wrong daily reputation values on the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I have a lot of wrongly calculated daily reputation values on my profile-reputation page:

[image: -8 Sep 14]
…
[image: 28 Sep 8]
…
[image: 19 Aug 22]
…
[image: -6 Jul 18]

On the other hand my total reputation value is calculated correctly and https://stackoverflow.com/reputation also shows correct data.

Is it related to this bug: [Why does reputation change for a day show up as 0 if it is +10?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107508/158912)

Comment: +1 *Very* strange.  Creepy.  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/648313/idolon?tab=reputation) the profile-rep page for anyone who wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a temporary bug around yesterday...a fix has since been pushed.  It was an issue around current/deleted votes for the daily totals query that wasn't using the correct types in non-accept cases.